# Ejecutar una secuencia de comandos FTP desde un archivo

Tags: bash, archivo, ftp, línea-de-comandos

Recurro a la comunidad ya que busque por todos lados y no encontre nada.
El tema es el siguiente.
Tengo una serie de scripts bash que suben, borran determinados archivos (no siempre los mismos) a un servidor FTP.
Con versiones antiguas de linux lo que hacia es grabar toda esa secuencia de comandos en un archivo de texto, y luego invocar el comando FTP pasandole con el signo < el archivo generado, por ejemplo:

```
echo 'cd planificacion' >baja.ftp
echo 'get ' $a_plantarde >>baja.ftp
echo 'get ' $a_planmanana >>baja.ftp
echo 'bye' >>baja.ftp
ftp ftp://$usuario:$clave@$ipTablet:$puerto < baja.ftp
```

Como les dije, esto andaba perfecto en versiones antiguas de linux.
En versiones nuevas esto:

```
ftp ftp://$usuario:$clave@$ipTablet:$puerto < baja.ftp
```

**NO funciona**, por lo tanto la forma de realizarla es esta:

```
ftp -inv $ipTablet $puerto<<FINFTP
    user $usuario $clave
    cd planificacion
    get $a_plantarde
    get $a_planmanana
    bye
FINFTP
```

Pero tengo el problema que la cantidad de archivos a subir o bajar y sus nombres son dinamicos, por lo tanto no puedo usar esta forma, o no me doy cuenta como hacerlo. La solucion, para mi, seria poder pasarle la lista de comandos en el archivo que genero y subo, por ejemplo, de esta forma:

```
for archivo in ../prepara/*.csv; do

            hora=`date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M"`
            longitud=`expr ${#archivo} - 7 `
            indice=${archivo:$longitud:3}
            nombre="entre$indice.csv"
            nombreM="mixer$indice.csv"
            nombremixer="mixer$indice-$hora.csv"
            nombreentr="entr$indice-$hora.csv"

            if [ -f ../entrega/$nombre ];
            then
                tamanionombreM=`stat -c %s ../prepara/$nombreM`
                tamanionombreE=`stat -c %s ../entrega/$nombre`
                if [ $tamanionombreM -gt 0 ];
                then
                    echo "put $nombreM">>llevamixer.ftp
                fi


                if [ $tamanionombreE -gt 0 ];
                then
                    echo "put ../entrega/$nombre">>llevamixer.ftp
                fi

                
                echo "get $nombre" >> llevamixer.ftp
                echo "delete $nombre" >> llevamixer.ftp
            fi
        done
        echo 'bye'>> llevamixer.ftp
        
        ftp ftp://$usuario:$clave@$ipTablet:$puerto < llevamixer.ftp
```

Agradeceria cualquier tipo de ayuda al respecto.
Atte, Ariel